# Avoid duplicates in mongoose insertMany()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**The question is marked duplicate wrongly. It is a different situation all together.**

I have a database containing roughly 27000 users. I want to insert more users to it from a csv file. Basically each user can uniquely identified by the email Id. I want to enter 43000 more such emails to the database. I am planning to use

```
Users.insertMany(emailArray,options,callback)
```

I want that if the email id already exists, it should not enter the record to the database. Checking for each email id in the database and updating individually seems inefficient. `insertMany` seems faster. Can I work my way around using `insertMany`?

**Current Approach::**

```
csv()
    .fromFile(path)
    .on('json', (jsonObj) => {
    var email = jsonObj.email;
    delete jsonObj.email;
    var profile = jsonObj;
    User.addEmails(email, profile, function (err, res) {
        if (err == "User already exists") {
            console.log("user already exists");
            } else {
            console.log(res);
            }
        })
    })
    .on('done', (error) => {
        console.log('end');
        fs.unlink(path);
        callback(null, "Done");
    })
```

Add emails function

```
module.addEmails = function(email, profile, callback){
    User.findOne({email: email}, function(err, res){
        if(err)
            throw err;
        else if(res){
            callback("User already exists");
        }
        else{
            User.create({email: email, profile: profile},callback);             
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Those are very bad duplicate examples... One is python, and definitely does not use mongoose and the other is for one document only, not bulk. I advice you to use updateMany (introduced in v3.2) with the upsert option. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.updateMany  & https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#db.collection.updateMany

Comment: @NicoVanBelle So using upsert would replace the existing doc right? In that case, I also have some fields in the doc that cannot be removed else would lead to major data loss